# Hide exit and settings button for Google Cardboard Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr

We are using Unity to build a 360 video player which works on newer phones. We are experiencing a problem when building to older phones where we can see the exit and settings button in the top right and left corners. I am unable to find where GVR is calling the function to draw these buttons in order to disable to call.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use 0.6 version GoogleSDK, with Unity 5.6. There are lot more options, if u build Cardboard app this is probably best sdk version for you (not for Daydream apps).

[CardboardMain Setup SDK0.6](http://prntscr.com/hkraq2)

Answer (score 0):

We made it work in Google VR Android version 1.18.4 (we used Unity Package Manager). Credit to my boss who found the solution

I created a fork with the necessary files included in case you have a hard time recompiling them. https://github.com/cdr9042/gvr-unity-sdk

Open gvr.aar using WinRAR in Packages/Google VR Android/Plugins/Android/ (locate it by right click > Show in Explorer)

Decompile the file classes.jar located inside

Go to com/google/vr/cardboard in the decompiled folder. You'll find the file UiLayer.java there.

Edit UiLayer.java:

Find and change these lines:

```
    //change from this.isSettingsButtonEnabled = true;
    this.isSettingsButtonEnabled = false;  

public boolean getBackButtonEnabled() {
    //change from return (this.backButtonListener != null);
    return false;
}
```

Recompile the modified UiLayer.java to make a new .jar file. You can name them uilayer.jar

Copy gvr.aar to somewhere else

Open the copied gvr.aar with WinRAR 
Open the classes.jar file in the WinRAR window
Go to com/google/vr/cardboard deletes all the UiLayer$*.class & UiLayer.class files

Now you have a new uilayer.jar and a modified gvr.aar files. Place them in Assets/Plugins/Android in your project.

Remove the old gvr.aar files in Packages/Google VR Android/Plugins/Android/. You'll have to locate it in explorer to delete it